# How to print log of tests (pass/failed) while they are running in suite?

Tags: java, junit, automation, junit4, suite

I have suite which contains couple of tests. I want to print for each test if it pass or fail when the test finish to run.
I don't want to add code for each test cause I have a lot of tests, I need to do it in the suite.
This is an example of one suite that I have:

```
    @RunWith(ConcurrentSuite.class)
    @Concurrent(threads = 6)
    @Suite.SuiteClasses({
        test1.class,
        test2.class,
        test3.class,
        test4.class,
    })
    public class ExampleSuite {

    }
```

tnx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your test classes all inherit from an abstract base test class, you could add a Testwatcher to this one and then implement any reaction you want to a test fail or a test success :

```
abstract class BaseTest {

@Rule
public TestWatcher watchman = new TestWatcher() {
// define logger here

    @Override
    protected void failed(Throwable e, Description description) {
        logger.error(description, e);
    }

    @Override
    protected void succeeded(Description description) {
        logger.info(description);
    }
};
```